# Can this mind control parasite work?

Tags: science-based, biology, brain, mind-control

I want to create a hard science parasite, this parasite consists of a symbiosis of a slime mold and neurons, it enters the host and branches by attaching to the organism. Could my organism control a human brain?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you want it to work in your world it will work. If you don't want it to work in your world it won't. Is there some constraint you've imposed on your world that is making it difficult to consistently allow for such a critter to do what you want? Can you describe the constraint and why it's a problem?

Comment: Please read the [tag wiki entry for hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/hard-science/info). It isn't an appropriate tag to use here.

Comment: It's obviously physically possible for a mind control parasite to exist, because minds are based on the brain and advanced enough rewiring could do enough. Is there some reason you think this shouldn't work?

Comment: How much influence does the parasite need to have to be considered control? The rabies virus famously causes its hosts to develop a fear of water. Would you consider that enough influence to say the rabies virus controls the host?

Comment: Welcome Zenobia, this question is probably not ready for a public listing. Please go through [our help section](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and see how to create a specific question in here. For example, “control” can mean many things and any expert help needs a lot of details before answering. Your question may get closed until it meets site requirements. It can open again after appropriate edits.

Comment: queen Zenobia welcome ! Tip #1:  take a bigger animal (bird size) and let your brain sucker control only a small part of the brain. Like your fingertips.. or fake memory.. ask if that can work. Tip #2: **put more text** to explain, else you get closed. That is important. I have to vote close, there is not enough information to answer the question. Think of a new one...

Answer (score 1):

**No, not really**

Disregarding problems with parasite itself (Why slime mold is it's part ? From where neurons came ? Also name "slime mold" doesn't even describe singular type of organism and is a very poor umbrella term) it is not possible for this organism to control human brain. Two main reasons:

1. Most fungal and parasitic brain infections are lethal or extremely dangerous. It would have to pass trough blood–brain barrier and it is possible, but the sole presence of this parasite next to the brain could kill the host due to disrupting brain's homeostasis with byproducts of it's metabolism. Not very good for parasite's survival.
2. This organism is way too simplistic. A few fungal cells and neurons is not enough to control human brain, even if you would somehow engineer this organism into existence, gave it ability to use those neurons and implant it into someone's brain it couldn't control them, it could probably interfere with brain's activity by firing random electrical signals, which could be extremely debilitating, but far from your goal.

It is simply not feasible for a parasite to control human's brain in a hard-science setting. Controlling behaviour is another story though, there are parasites that can do that: Cordyceps Fungus (controls behaviour of insects) and Toxoplasma gondii (controls behaviour of mice) also rabies, not a parasite but forces changes in bahviour. Read up on those three. Hope i helped.